# How do i set UIDatePicker's date to another date?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsdate, uidatepicker

I have tried various things, including:

```
[timepicker setDate: [NSDate mondayalarmtime]];
```

and

```
timepicker.date = mondayalarmtime;
```

Each time, this line crashes the simulator. My mondayalarmtime is defined in viewDidLoad here:

```
 NSDateFormatter *inputFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [inputFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate *inputDate = [inputFormat dateFromString: @"2011-01-01 09:00:00"];

 NSLog (@"The input date %@", inputDate);

 NSDate *mondayalarmtime = inputDate;
```

The NSLog returns:

```
The input date 2011-01-01 09:00:00 +0000
```

Putting an NSLog asking for mondayalarmtime just before it tries to set thet imepicker to mondayalarmtime returns the same..

```
Mondays alarm time.. 2011-01-01 09:00:35 +0000
```

And then when it tries to set the timepicker date to mondayalarmtime, it crashes with the report:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

Comment: Sounds like a classic memory mismanagement problem.  We need to see more code.

Comment: 1) Are you using ARC, 2) Why are you locally declaring mondayalarmtime in your viewDidLoad if it is an ivar, 3) Is the 35 second difference in your logs a typo or what you actually see?

Comment: Sorry, got confused by dates (how ironic) I thought this was a new question! January disease.

Answer (score 6):

You are sending the mondayalarmtime message to NSDate. NSDate does not understand this message

Try setting a property with mondayalarmtime and calling the getter

```
[timepicker setDate:[self mondayalarmtime]];
```